# How to pass values between events in JS?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, event-handling, event-listener

I'm creating simple currency converter as uni project. Doing everything in Django and vanilla JS.
Consider the following problem:
I have some eventListener which uses external API to change image (country flag) on the page. Flag selection is based on select tag in html. Next after that trigger will go with certain picks, I would like to trigger next event; to get from other API value of picked currencies from 1st event. So I need to pass that value from select tag from 1st eventListener into second one.

So basically I have select tag which gives me values from that selection:

```
const select1 = document.getElementById('selector1');
const select2 = document.getElementById('selector2');

function controlFlag(element, flagId) {
  element.addEventListener('change', function () {
    const selectedCountry = element.value;
    const apiUrl = 'https://www.countryflagicons.com/FLAT/64/' + selectedCountry + '.png';
    const flagImage = document.getElementById(flagId);
    flagImage.src = apiUrl;
  });
}
controlFlag(select1, 'flag1');
controlFlag(select2, 'flag2');
```

Next i would like to pass "selectedCountry" into other event:

```
function getRates(currency_name) {
    if(currency_name === "pln"){ return 1; }
    return fetch(`http://api.nbp.pl/api/exchangerates/rates/a/${currency_name}`)
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then(json_data => {
            console.log(json_data);
            const value_in_pln = json_data.rates[0].mid;
            console.log(`currency_name = ${currency_name} and value_in_pln = ${value_in_pln}`);
            return value_in_pln;
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.error(error);
        });
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  if (conversionButton) {
    conversionButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
        console.log('Button clicked!');
        console.log(`curr1NAME ========== ${curr1Name}`)
        console.log(`curr2NAME ========== ${curr2Name}`)
        Promise.all([getRates(), getRates()]) // here goes 2 currency names
        .then(values => {
            const tab = values;
            console.log("CURR1 = " + tab[0]);
            console.log("CURR2 = " + tab[1]);
            console.log(`${pickedCurrency1.value} to ${pickedCurrency2.value} = ${(tab[0] / tab[1]).toFixed(4)}`);
            console.log(`Amount for curr1 to curr2: ${valueForInput.value}`);
            let valueForOutput = valueForInput.value * ((tab[0] / tab[1]).toFixed(2));
            console.log("valueForOutput = " + valueForOutput);
            outputRatio.innerHTML = `${valueForInput.value} ${curr1Name} => ${valueForOutput} ${curr2Name}`
        });
    });
  } else {
    console.log("Button Not Working!");
  }
});
```

Both codes works perfectly but do not update values in line: Promise.all([getRates(), getRates()]) // here goes 2 currency names. How to pass arguments into, getRates()?

Comment: You can declare a variable in the file that will hold the values of the selected currency. Update it when user selects something else and use the same variable while calling `getRates`

Comment: Simple but good idea. What file should i use? Just simple JS file and have some structure to insert data from one event, then get data to second?

Comment: You need to do it in the same file in which the rest of your JS is.